# Profiling option for application developed using PEGA

Tags: performance, jprofiler, pega

I am from Performance Engineering background, we have a workflow application developed using PEGA.Is it possible to Profile that application using JProfiler or is there any tool available exclusively to Profile the applications developed using PEGA

Comment: You can use Pega application profiler.

Answer (score 1):

A long as it's running on the JVM, you can profile it with JProfiler.

In the JProfiler GUI, invoke

*Session->Integration Wizards->New Remote Integration*

and follow the steps in the wizard. Basically, you will have to insert a VM parameter that enabled profiling.

Alternatively, you can use *Session->Quick Attach* to profile any running JVM on your system.